# Listening to events in light DOM

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom

The [Polymer guide on events](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html) is very straightforward. What it doesn't explain, is this: is it at all possible to listen to events in the element's *light DOM*? (That is, elements distributed in `<content></content>`)

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're trying to accomplish? Here's a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/boxanu/edit?html,output) to get started.

Comment: This is what I came up with: http://jsbin.com/lajunu/edit . Is this how you do it?

Comment: Your solution works fine. Are you looking for something more?

Comment: I was asking if there was another, less verbose way of doing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as I found it, the way I did it is how you do it!

Comment: could you put your solution in the answer? That JS Bin doesn't seem to have the answer anymore.

Comment: I have no idea why the JSBin is no longer updated. I thought JSBin kept revisions in the event of a change...? I have no idea today what my solution was, it was 1.5 years ago. Sorry!